# Eclipse with Intel C Compiler ICC

Tags: linux, eclipse, icc

I am trying to use icc with Eclipse on Ubuntu 12.04. icc works perfectly from the commandline. 
After installing icc I have installed eclipse-platform using apt-get.

I am following instructions give here : http://www.wrgrid.group.shef.ac.uk/icebergdocs/intelv14docs/en_US/get_started_lc.htm

After following these steps I get the following error :

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Intel(R) C++ Compiler XE 14.0 for Linux* OS 8.1.0 (com.intel.compiler.cdt.feature.group 8.1.0)
  Missing requirement: Intel C/C++ Standard Make Build UI 8.1.0 (com.intel.compiler.cdt.make.ui 8.1.0) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.cdt.make.ui 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Intel(R) C++ Compiler XE 14.0 for Linux* OS 8.1.0 (com.intel.compiler.cdt.feature.group 8.1.0)
    To: com.intel.compiler.cdt.make.ui [8.1.0]
```

Please help me resolve this. What could have gone wrong?

Comment: I would avoid compiling directly thru eclipse, and just code a plain old `Makefile`; I'm pretty sure Eclipse can be instructed to run `make` for compilation (and for C or C++ code, I don't recommend Eclipse; Emacs is very good).

Comment: But, I would still like to use eclipse rather than learning a new tool like emacs. btw, I am a VIM fan

Comment: Then use `vim` (with `make`) or instruct your Eclipse to build your project using `make`; this has the great advantage that other people could build your project much more easily (just typing `make`, without requiring a sophisticated installation of Eclipse which yourself are struggling with).

Answer (score 1):

Please note the requirement include both eclipse and CDT. You could install both of them with

```
$ sudo apt-get install eclipse-cdt
```

Only `eclipse-platform` in ubuntu repo does not cover the CDT part.

If it still not work, you could consider download a standalone version of `Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers` here.

```
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/
```

Comment: Installing eclipse-cdt does not help. I am trying out standalone version. I will post back in case that works

Comment: I think the best way is to use the standalone version. Important point was to install cdt-master before proceeding to install ICC with eclipse. http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-c-compiler-for-linux-using-intel-compilers-with-the-eclipse-ide-pdf

Comment: what is 'cdt-master'?

Comment: I am not really sure what exactly is cdt-master, but I followed the website I posted in my earlier comment and now I can run icc with eclipse

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Intel's chain of compilers available in Cluster Studio XE 2013/Parallel Studio XE 2013/ C++ Studio XE 2013/ Composer XE 2013 will work on:
*Eclipse Kepler 4.3 with CDT 8.0.0 installed*.

Do not download Eclipse Kepler for C++ as it comes bundled with a CDT version higher than 8.0.0 which is not supported by the Intel plugin.

Therefore, download Eclipse Kepler standard, and then download `cdt-master-8.0.0.zip` (available from http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php). In Eclipse, click on *Help*>*Install New Software*>*Add*>point to the `cdt-master-8.0.0.zip` archive.

After the installation is complete and Eclipse restarted, go to to *Help*>*Install New Software*>*Add* and add the location where the *eclipse_support/cdt8.0/eclipse folder* is located.

On my system, it is located here:

> /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.2.144/eclipse_support/cdt8.0/eclipse

In the Install window, unclick *Group items by category*.

Yes, we know that our tools should be upwards compatible. The devs are working to fix these issues in the XE 2015 line of products.

Sources: Intel employee.